# Clutter messing up animations

Tags: python, linux, animation, clutter

Clutter is not doing the full animation.

This is my current code:

```
from gi.repository import Clutter, Gtk
import sys

def onClick(actor, event):
    actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [280])  # clutter does not seem to be running this line
    actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [20])

def main():
    Clutter.init(sys.argv)

    # Colors
    red = Clutter.Color().new(255, 0, 0, 255)
    black = Clutter.Color().new(0, 0, 0, 255)

    # Create Stage
    stage = Clutter.Stage()
    stage.set_title("Basic Usage")
    stage.set_size(400, 200)
    stage.set_color(black)

    # Rectangle Actor
    actor = Clutter.Rectangle()
    actor.set_size(100, 50)
    actor.set_position(150, 100)
    actor.set_color(red)
    actor.set_reactive(True)
    actor.connect("button-press-event", onClick)

    # Add Actor to the Stage
    stage.add_actor(actor)
    stage.connect("destroy", lambda w:  Clutter.main_quit())
    stage.show_all()

    Clutter.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Behold this illustration of my problem:

[image]

For those of you who don't like gifs, here is my problem described in words:
I want the actor to move from the middle to the right, then all the way to the left. Instead it just moves from the middle straight to the left.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Would you mind switching the order of the animate statements and telling me what it does?  I think I know the answer to this.

Comment: @Stephan  Thanks. Switching the two lines makes it move from the middle to the right, instead of the from the middle to the left.

Comment: Ok, I know the answer, posting it in a sec

Comment: ... hell that's how we should explain our questions to each other. +1 just for the gif!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like the documentation for ClutterActor.animate() says:

> Calling this function on an actor that is already being animated will
>   cause the current animation to change with the new final values, the
>   new easing mode and the new duration
>   https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/clutter-Implicit-Animations.html#clutter-actor-animate

which means that the following code:

```
actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [280])
actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [20])
```

is exactly equivalent to:

```
actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [20])
```

which is what you're seeing.

if you want to chain up two animations you have to connect to the `completed` signal of `ClutterAnimation`, using the `connect_after` function, so that Clutter can create a new animation:

```
def moveLeft (animation, actor):
    actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [20])

actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [280]).connect_after('completed', moveLeft)
```

I'd like to point out that `animatev()` and `ClutterAnimation` are deprecated; they can be replaced by using an explicit `Clutter.KeyframeTransition` or an implicit transition, for instance:

```
from gi.repository import Clutter

Clutter.init(None)

stage = Clutter.Stage()
stage.connect('destroy', lambda x: Clutter.main_quit())

actor = Clutter.Actor()
actor.set_background_color(Clutter.Color.get_static(Clutter.StaticColor.RED))
actor.set_reactive(True)
actor.set_size(32, 32)
stage.add_child(actor)
actor.set_position(82, 82)

def moveLeft(actor):
    actor.set_x(20)

def moveRight(actor):

    actor.set_easing_duration(1000)
    actor.set_easing_mode(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR)
    actor.set_x(280)
    actor.connect('transition-stopped::x', lambda a, n, t: moveLeft(actor))

actor.connect('button-press-event', lambda a, e: moveRight(actor))

stage.show()
Clutter.main()
```

it can be arbitrarily more complex than this; you also need to remember to disconnect the `transition-stopped::x` signal handler, and restore the easing state to avoid creating implicit animations every time you change the actor's state, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
def onClick(actor, event):
    animation1 = actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [280])
    animation1.connect_after(
        'completed',
        lambda animation: actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [20])
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do these to lines immediately after each other

```
def onClick(actor, event):
    actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [280])
    actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [20])
```

Clutter does them both without waiting for the other to finish.  This means that the first command has almost no time to move the agent at all before the second command takes over.

Here is an example of using the "completed" signal:

```
def onClick(actor, event):
    animate(actor)

def animate(actor):
    firstAnimation = actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [280]) 

    firstAnimation.connect_after("completed", moveLeft)

def moveLeft():
    self.actor.animatev(Clutter.AnimationMode.LINEAR, 1000, ["x"], [20])
```

[Here is the documentation on clutter animations](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/clutteranimation.html)
[Here is the documentation on the "completed" signal](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/clutter-Implicit-Animations.html#ClutterAnimation-completed)
[Here is some working example code](http://www.eurion.net/python-snippets/snippet/Clutter%20Animation.html)

Comment: When I add this between the two lines:
while (actor.get_x() < 280):
    continue

My CPU spikes and it never does anything. The actor stays put.

Comment: @DanielTA I suspected as much, you need to do it the legit way, and not the hack way.  I finished the real answer recently

Comment: @DanielTA Sorry for the bad answer, it was just a temporary hack while i submitted this one, please see updated answer.

Comment: You are getting closer, it moves it to the left, but immediately, it doesn't animate. It animates to the right and then just appears on the left side.

Comment: @DanielTA [here](http://www.eurion.net/python-snippets/snippet/Clutter%20Animation.html) is what i'm trying to emulate  Maybe read that and try to tweak?  I'll keep looking into it

Comment: Ok. Thanks for spending time on this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34029/discussion-between-stephan-and-danielta)